# Why will this modal link not open when this javascript is being used?

Tags: javascript, css, menu, modal-dialog

I'm playing around with some simple code (partially made by me, partially free stuff from online) to build a simple html page which opens modal windows with an embedded iframe to display a PDF.

Here's the problem. In my table, I call to open the modal as such:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">Example</a>
```

Then I have my other modal items in div tags, and everything works EXCEPT in Internet Explorer 11. There, clicking on that link in the menu opens nothing UNLESS I remove the following javascript file that the free css template generator marks as "optional to use". I wouldn't use it altogether but it keeps the table centered and looking good in IE11.

Here is a fiddle with just the JS to save space:

```
function t() {
    for (var af = 0; af < arguments.length; ++af) {
        if (typeof(arguments[af]) == "undefined") {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/CodyyCVPI2004/v3ayjy0b/

I think it has something to do with `ah.onclick` but I don't know anywhere near enough about JS to solve the problem. Any ideas? I simply just want to find out what in this javascript is preventing modal windows opening from anchor tags in my css table.

Comment: It appears that most of your example code is missing from the question and your jsfiddle doesn't work. If you want someone to be able to help, you will need to provide a working example.

Comment: Sorry - it has been fixed.

To see the problem, click the Open Modal or Cancel Rebill buttons. Observe that the modal opens. Then, go to the Readings & Meters Menu and choose cancel rebill. Observe no modal opens.

Comment: Just a recommendation, use descriptive names for methods and variables, its very hard to follow the code when all the methods are named `a(), w(), x(), t(), ...` and the variables are like `af, al, ak, K, v, C...`, it almost looks obfuscated code (at least the indentation is OK). It will be useful also for you if you reexamine the code after some time and realize that you forgot how it worked.

Comment: I agree it is difficult to follow. Unfortunately this JS was created by the CSS Menu building tool I used, so I didn't write it myself.